# java http authentication reuse between servlets

Tags: java, http, authentication, servlets

not sure how to formulate the question correctly.

i've got two web-apps: A with a servlet and B with two servlets, both protected by basic authentication in web.xml (deployed to weblogic server).

a user authenticates to A and to one of B's servlets (not sure if what i say here is total rubbish) using browser-native login/password window (that's managed by weblogic).

however, the servlet of application A should as well call the other of B's servlets and that requires authentication also.

the question is: can it be avoided? the user has already authenticated to both of web-apps, so  i'd like to just somehow reuse this authentication (i'm really not good at all these http session things terminology, don't throw rocks at me :)).

cookies can't be used it seems, as it is really server-side communication.

Answer (score 0):

following should fix the problem:

1. create `javax.servlet.Filter` that extracts jsessionid from requests and stores it per user somehow (in my case i put it to `org.springframework.security.core.Authentication` as `details`, making sure this filter runs after spring-security's one).
2. add it to each servlet-servlet request as cookie header:

   ```
   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.setRequestHeader("Cookie",
       "jsessionid="+org.springframework.security.core.Authentication.getDetails().toString());
   ```

   where appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your servlet code in app A:

```
URLConnection conn = new URL("http://hostname/appB/servlet1");
String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader("authorization");
if (null != authorizationHeader) {
    conn.setRequestProperty("authorization", authorizationHeader);
}
InputStream inStream = conn.getInputStream();
//Read from inStream in the usual way
```